# Square root of $\frac{2}{2^x}$; how do I find $x$?

Tags: exponentiation, square-numbers

I have this:

$$\sqrt{\frac{2}{2^x}} = 9.313225746154785 \times 10^{−10}$$

(sqrt(2/(2^x)))

How should I find $x$? I know it's 61 for this case, but I'd like to know how to solve it for when I don't. Thanks!

Comment: take log on both sides?

Comment: Do you mean $9.313225746154785\times 10^{−10}$ instead of $9.313225746154785e−10$?

Comment: Hint: $\frac{2}{2^x} = 2^{1-x}$

Comment: @Juanito Excuse me? Could you please explain that a bit more?
`HenningMakholm` Yes! How do you write that?
`Mathmo123` Yes, I checked and it's correct, thanks, I'll keep that for future calculations!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Distribute the power through the fraction.
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2^{x/2}}=9.313225746154785\times10^{-10}$$
Rearrange fractions.
$$\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9.313225746154785\times10^{-10}}=2^{x/2}$$
Take logarithms of both sides.
$$\log_2\left(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{9.313225746154785\times10^{-10}}\right)=\log_2\left(2^{x/2}\right)$$
Remove $x$ from the logarithm on the right by the log rule for powers.
$$x=2\log_2\left(\frac{2^{1/2}}{9.313225746154785\times10^{-10}}\right)$$
Rearrange with the log rules for fractions & multiplication.
$$\therefore\quad x=21-2\log_2(9.313225746154785)+20\log_2(5)\approx61$$

This relies on the fact that $9.313\ldots\approx\left(\frac{5}{4}\right)^{10}$